# How to remove a requested Backup file (.bak)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL server 2005 and above and I wondering if there is a way to remove a specific backup file from the default SQL backups folder...

I can find that backups folder by using the query below:

```
EXEC  master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'BackupDirectory'
```

The only way that I found was using the master.dbo.xp_delete_file operation, but the problem is that its cannot remove only one file (the requested one).

Any idea?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the call to `xp_delete_file` so that we might tell you why the call isn't working as you expect?

Comment: The call to the `xp_delete_file` operation is working but its can only clean backups older then a requested date:
`EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'E:\Database_Backups',N'bak','2009-03-07T16:45:17',1`

I look for a way to remove a requested backup file...

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`xp_cmdshell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) to spawn a Windows command shell and execute a given string, as in:

`xp_cmdshell 'del "E:\Database Backups\Some Database Backup.bak"'`

Combined with your code to determine the default backup folder, you could construct the appropriate string to delete a specific file.

Note that `xp_cmdshell` is locked down by default for security reasons (obviously, running any arbitrary command string would be bad).

Comment: Tx Michael, it works fine but I cannot use the `xp_cmdshell` because its security issues (in any appropriate company the DBA wont permit a free access to their servers).